# Does Dart 1.13 relax superinterface requirements for mixin applications?

Tags: inheritance, dart, mixins

In the following code from [Mixins in Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/mixins/#basic-concepts), an application of mixin `K` results in no warning, despite missing the superinterface method `twice()`:

```
class S {
  twice(int x) => 2 * x;
}

abstract class I {
  twice(x);
}

abstract class J {
  thrice(x);
}

class K extends S implements I, J {
  int thrice(x) => 3* x;
}

class B {
  twice(x) => x + x;
}

class A = B with K;

class D {
  double(x) => x+x;
}

// E missing 'twice', thus not conforming to
// superinterface S of K. Yet no warning in
// checked mode under Dart 1.13.
class E = D with K;

main() {
  /// A conforms to superinterface S of K
  assert(new A().twice (1) == 2);
  assert(new A().thrice(1) == 3);

  /// E conforms to superinterface S of K
//assert(new E().twice (1) == 2);  // NoSuchMethod 'twice'
  assert(new E().thrice(1) == 3);  // thrice() Provided by K
}
```

I'm mainly just wanting to fill in some holes in my understanding, so would appreciate someone pointing out any misuse of terms or bad concepts in my question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were changes to how mixins work in Dart version 1.13. It's implemented in the VM, but not yet in dart2js, and I'm not sure about the analyzer.

Still, `E` is a non-abstract class that doesn't implement its own interface (implements `I` but doesn't have a non-abstract `twice` member). That should cause a warning, mixins or no mixins.

On top of that, `K` extends `S`, so when using `K` as a mixin, the mixin application's superclass should also implement `S` which `D` doesn't. That should give another warning.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out E not implementing its own interface. I've seen it in the docs, somewhere, that this form of class creation with an assignment statement results, by default, in an abstract class. And that if you want a concrete class, to use the standard form "class E extends D with K {}".

Comment: BTW, using the above "standard" form of class statement also produces no warnings. So apparently the analyzer is a little behind the spec, here.